# Why do I get this output when using AVPlayer in Swift?

Tags: swift, audio, avplayer

I am trying to play an audio file using avplayer in swift, when I play a file i generated combining two files, i get this output

```
 playing file:"file location".m4a -- file:///
```

however when I play another remade sound file it plays fine, and i don't get the  -- file:/// in the output after playing it

this is how I am playing the audio

```
func play(url:NSURL) {
do {
    soundPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
    soundPlayer.volume = 1.0
    soundPlayer.play()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
} catch {
    print("failed")
}

}
```

and this is what I am using to concatenate two audio files

```
  func makeSounds(sounds: [NSURL], preName: String){
   let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    print(sounds)

    for sound in sounds {
    let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: sound as URL)
    let track =  avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
    let timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeMake(0, 600), duration: track.timeRange.duration)
    try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: track, at: composition.duration)

    }


    let documentDirectoryURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Urls.user)
    var fileDestinationUrl = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(SoundData.Name)\(preName).m4a")


    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
    assetExport?.outputURL = fileDestinationUrl


    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:
        {
            switch assetExport!.status
            {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                print("failed \(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                print("unknown\(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                print("waiting\(assetExport?.error)")
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                print("exporting\(assetExport?.error)")
            default:
                soundsToPlay.soundLocation = String(describing: fileDestinationUrl!)
                print("Audio Concatenation Complete")
            }
    })



}
```

the audio file location appears correct to the url i am setting it to be exported to, but it doesn't play the sound file, i just get that error

Answer (score 0):

AVAssetExportSession needs a path string in 'File' format, which is usually obtained through URL.relativeString, which includes 'file:///'